# Google Drive API Files.List Query String

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to know the keywords and parameters for formulating a query string
for the google drive api list.setQ method.

Here is my code:

```
FileList files = drive.files().list()
            .setQ("trashed=true")
            .setMaxResults(100)
            .execute();
```

So far, I found "TRASHED" is valid parameter which I can use to list all the
trashed files in my google drive. It would be nice to have the complete list of parameters. Is that list available?

Comment: new way of writing the query `.setQ` is `list(q=('trashed=true')).execute()`

Answer (score 9):

The Google Drive SDK documentation lists all fields and operators you can use in your queries:

https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

Comment: Just noticed that the Android Drive client have a typesafe query builder. Do you know if there is an equivalent for server-side Java projects?