# Google Drive API Files.List Query String - "not" operator

Tags: google-drive-api

Similar to this question [Google Drive API Files.List Query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457235/google-drive-api-files-list-query-string) in the sense that I would like to know all the syntax for the setQ method: FileList files = drive.files().list() .setQ("trashed=true") .setMaxResults(100) .execute();

In particular I would like to get the files (not folders) from the query.

To get folders this query works: `request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false "`

I have tried different combinations, like

```
request.Q = "not mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false "
request.Q = "mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false "
```

etc

Some run but ignore the not, some just crash.

Is there a way to get a list of only files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no negations in the Drive API query language, sorry! This is a great feature that we should be looking to add.

Answer (score 2):

The answer seems to be old, currently googlde drive api accept != operator.

Hope it helps,
Alvaro.