# How to improve the efficiency of searching particular Google Drive file in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, google-drive-api

I developed a Java program to search particular file in particular folder on Google Drive. It uses DFS(Depth First Search) algorithm to search.

However, the searching efficiency is very bad. If the file is located in the "later" or deeper folder, the program will take several minutes to find it if found, or sometimes it will be time out and respond an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

The program is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DriveSearch driveSearch = new DriveSearch();
    String searchResult = driveSearch.fetchData("F1b1ZuRUpPLWh6",
            "test.txt");
    System.out.println(searchResult);
}

public String fetchData(String folderID, String searchFileName) {
    String result = "";

               ~~~~~  Skip Codes for Authorization  ~~~~
    // try {
    //     try {
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Begin search time
    //         String pageToken = null;
    //         do {
    System.out.println("=== Begin Search ===");
    File searchResult = recursiveSearch(folderID, searchFileName);
    System.out.println("=== End Search ===");
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // End search time
    long totTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    System.out.println("This search takes " + totTime + " seconds to find the file.");
    if (searchResult != null) {
        result = searchResult.getName();
    }
    //             pageToken = fileList.getNextPageToken();
    //         } while (pageToken != null);
    //     } catch (IOException e) {
    //         result = "invalid_grant";
    //         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    //     }
    // } catch (Throwable t) {
    //     t.printStackTrace();
    // }
    return result;
}

public File recursiveSearch(String folderID, String searchFileName) throws IOException {
    File searchResult = null;
    FileList fileList = service.files().list().setQ("'" + folderID + "' in parents and trashed = false")
        // .setSpaces("drive")
        .setCorpora("user").setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)").execute();
    List<File> items = fileList.getFiles();

    for (File file : items) {
        if (file.getName().equals(searchFileName)) {
            searchResult = file;
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is found!");
            return searchResult;
        } else if (file.getMimeType().equals("application/vnd.google-apps.folder")) {
            System.out.println("Recursive Search");
            System.out.println("file.getId() is " + file.getId());
            searchResult = recursiveSearch(file.getId(), searchFileName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("file name is " + file.getName());
        }
    }
    return searchResult;
}
```

Since specific file can be found immediately on Google Drive search bar, can it also be immediately found in specific folder? If yes, what should I do to improve the searching efficiency? Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: I´m pretty sure that it´s not your searching algorithm that takes so long but rather the statement 'fileList.getFiles()'

Answer (score 4):

The expensive part are the calls to Google Drive in each recursive call. They are not necessary. You can fetch the list of all files in one call:

```
/**
 * Read file list from Google Drive.
 * @param service an authenticated <code>Drive</code> object needed to send the request
 * @return Answer the list of files.
 * @throws IOException
 */
protected List<File> readFiles( final Drive service ) throws IOException {
    final List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    final Files.List request = service.files().list();
    do {
        final FileList files = request.execute();
        result.addAll(files.getItems());
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
    return result;
}
```

Afterwards search the list of files for your files. Of course you may add a filter o your request as you did in your code, e.g. to filter out trashed files.

Comment: A question about that: Is it possible to send some kind of filtered request to the drive? I imagine this would further increase the performance as you won´t need to download the whole list but just the filtered ones.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. It the same request type you used before. You may add the setQ() part as before, but do not filter for the folder.

Comment: Makes sense. However what I actually meant was more like sending some kind of sql querry to the server which does the searching for me. That would save a lot of time as you would just need to download one file. However I just realized that would make the Google Drive servers pretty funurable to ddos attacks so it´s not quite likely isn´t it?

Comment: IMHO not worse than the REST interface. But I don't know about another query interface different from the one mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim: my reading of their SDK doc at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters indicates that you can in fact do that. For example, you can ask for all files that start with "foo", in all directories. It would return only those files.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks. But the file structure has many sub-folders and grand-folders and so on. Could it search particular file in the very deep folder? I tried your code but it responds "Read timed out".

Comment: @Stefan: Do you know how to setMaxResults? The setMaxResult seems not appear in v3?

Comment: The code is from a working program of mine. I have no idea where the time out comes from.
According to the manual, you should be able to search for the file name independent of the folder: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters
But I have not tried that. And I don't know of a method to set the max. results, there is only the pagination (defaults to 100, I did not need to change that until now).
However there is an answer here, which uses setMaxResults(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457235/google-drive-api-files-list-query-string
I did not try that either.

Comment: @Stefan: Is the searching time very short if you use your program to search a specific file which is in a specific folder?

Comment: Its significantly faster to pass a unique search parameter. I have 293 files on my drive. The request o get all file models needs between 1900 and 3500 millies. To get a single file by name (title='<filename>') needs between 480 and 780 millies for me. Serializing,unserializing, and the transfer of the larger result dominates the search time on the server. (I have timed the request of an already authenticated service object.)

Comment: @Stefan: Could you please share your code or search function? I wonder how it could be so fast. Without quick search efficiency, my project will be pending. Many thanks!

Comment: Its the exact code above plus a setq() after the service.files().list().